# Exception thrown in main method in JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I'm facing some problems while executing my main function using javafx .It appears to be a problem in loading the fxml file if I'm not mistaken but I can't seem to find how to fix it .

Exception message:

```
Exception in Application start method java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2434)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
at Gestion.view.MainClass.initialisationContenu(MainClass.java:57)
at Gestion.view.MainClass.start(MainClass.java:28)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
... 1 more
Exception running application Gestion.view.MainClass
```

Main function:

```
package Gestion.view;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainClass extends Application {
    private Stage stagePrincipal;
    private BorderPane conteneurPrincipal;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        stagePrincipal = primaryStage;

        stagePrincipal.setTitle("Application de gestion du centre socio-médical OCP");


        initialisationConteneurPrincipal();
        initialisationContenu();
    }

    private void initialisationConteneurPrincipal() {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(MainClass.class.getResource("Welcome.fxml"));
        try {

            conteneurPrincipal = (BorderPane) loader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(conteneurPrincipal);
            stagePrincipal.setScene(scene);
            stagePrincipal.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void initialisationContenu() {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass()
                .getClassLoader()
                .getResource("Acceuil1.fxml")
        );
        try {
            AnchorPane conteneurPersonne = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
            conteneurPrincipal.setCenter(conteneurPersonne);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public Stage getStage() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I've already searched in other similar questions , but the answers given did not work for me.

Comment: I am guessing this is French? Unfortunately, there is not a French version of StackOverflow available and you'll need to use English.

Comment: I am glad that there is no french (or other non-english) version of StackOverflow because that would only split up the combined international knowledge into much less knowledgable fractions.

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry ... I didn't pay attention ... thanks for pointing it out , I'll edit it in english rn .

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that [FXMLLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#load--) can't load an object hierarchy from FXML documents.

Fix it by updating the URLs:

```
loader.setLocation(MainClass.class.getResource("/fxml/Welcome.fxml"));

.getResource("/fxml/Acceuil1.fxml")
```

and moving *Welcome.fxml* and *Acceuil1.fxml* to **src/main/resources/fxml** directory.